# socket.IO-objc vs. AZSocketIO

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, sockets, socket.io

From the [list of Socket.IO implementations in other languages](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki#in-other-languages), we can see that there are two alternatives written in `Objective-C`. My question is related to the pros and the cons of each of these two libraries.

[socket.IO-objc](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) seems more complete and has a better documentation, but I'd also like to know which advantages does [AZSocketIO](https://github.com/pashields/AZSocketIO) provide to consider if these advantages are important enough for my project to choose one or the other.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone that has used one of these could give me some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AZSocketIO has CocoaPods. That's a win for me.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, it seems like AZSocketIO implements an automatic reconnection strategy, and SocketIO.objc doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who come across to this question; please note that both AZSocketIO and socket.IO-objc support maximum 0.9.x and now socket.io has official [Swift implementation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift).